# Optional argument in Drupal hook_menu implementation

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-routes

How can I set one of the page arguments in my drupal menu item as an optional page argument?

I have

```
$items['activities_list/%/%']=array(
'title callback' => 'activities_list_title',
'title arguments' =>array(1),
'description' =>'All the Indicators divided by Coutry',
'page callback' => 'activities_list',
'access arguments' => array('access ppi'),
'page arguments' => array(1,2)
);
```

If I call activities_list/76 for example without a third argument I will receive a page not found error. How Can I set the Third parameter as an optional one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's easier than you think :). Don't set any arguments in your path and just pass them to your "page callback" function.

```
$items['activities_list']=array(
  'title callback' => 'activities_list_title',
  'description' =>'All the Indicators divided by Coutry',
  'page callback' => 'activities_list',
  'access arguments' => array('access ppi'),
);
```

And the page callback function would look like this:

```
function activities_list($arg1, $arg2)
{
    // Your code goes here...
    drupal_set_title(activities_list_title($arg1, $arg2));
}
```

You can alter the page title using the following code. (Not tested, kindly let me know if it worked):

```
function activities_list_title($arg_1, $arg_2)
{
    $title = "";
    // Your code goes here
    return $title;
}
```

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have a problem that the title argument is no longer working.

Comment: Added a solution for than. Kindly try it and let me know if it worked.

Comment: This will throw a warning if you don't pass any argument to the callback function.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can. If you did this instead with only one wildcard:

```
$items['activities_list/%']=array(
  'title callback' => 'activities_list_title',
  'title arguments' =>array(1),
  'description' =>'All the Indicators divided by Coutry',
  'page callback' => 'activities_list',
  'access arguments' => array('access ppi'),
  'page arguments' => array(1,2)
);
```

This will then work for a URL like **activities_list/foo**, but if you then had a URL like **activities_list/foo/bar** you can still get the value of **bar** in the page callback as it is still passed to that function by **'page arguments' => array(1,2)**.

Or alternatively you can call it by using **arg(2)** in your page callback.